# How do I earn gems in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I play clash of clans and I'm at lvl 5 town hall. I need gems for some of the things I want to do. Other than spending real money, what things earn me gems?

Comment: I edited this to make it a little more presentable. I also removed the bit about hacks- we don't answer questions about cheating in multiplayer games.

Comment: I have to issue a downvote because "what about hacks" was added back into the question.

Comment: This is currently your only marginally acceptable question. Out of five, two have been deleted outright, and two have been closed. They're ALL low quality, and heavily downvoted. Please take the time to go through the tour, and familiarize yourself with what we are and how we work. Unless you put some effort into your contributions, I'm afraid you're going to continue to be met with downvotes and close votes. Help us help you.

Comment: @Frank It took two edits to get it this acceptable since after the first she insisted on ruining it.

Comment: @Studoku Which is why I'm attempting to familiarize them with how we work. Perhaps a forlorn hope, but an attempt must be made.

Answer (score 11):

You can earn gems for free in the following ways:

1. Clearing up the trees, bushes, rocks, etc. that spawn around your village. Rocks do not re-spawn once you remove them.
2. Earning achievements in the game rewards you with gems. Check your achievement progress in-game to see how many you can earn and from what.
3. Once you've unlocked your Builder Base and reconstructed the Gem Mine, it will start producing gems for you.
4. Each league season, the top three clans are awarded gems, split equally among the top 10 players in each clan.

Comment: For #3, to be a top clan/player, you'll have paid for the privilege, guaranteed. Not sure if that can really be counted as a way to get free gems.

Comment: Yeah, just listing them all. It's not IMPOSSIBLE to get there for free. But I would bet that those that are there now probably have paid for it. But hey, once you get there, it's free ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can also get gems by removing gem boxes which give 25 gems.

Answer (score 2):

The only (legit) way to get gems without paying real money is to destroy these rocks, stones and bushes all around your village. They will respawn after some time and have a chance to drop some gems (its not guaranteed that they always drop gems). Also you can get them for completing achievements.

Comment: Can I plz have more options?

Comment: @user If there are more options, they will be listed. We play games, not hack them.

Comment: There arent any more options I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to get gems in clash of clans. they are as follows

- Go on removing obstacles.(i think you can get 6 gems each day by doing this. not sure it is 6 or less).
- This method is only affordable if you are **really** willing to get gems and can't resist the treasure option in buy mode. but this method takes money. yeah **real money** so be sure whatever  of these 2 methods you choose.